# Multi Threading with room database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Recently I started using room database in my android app. I am getting some problems when trying to access database from multiple threads. I am using same instance of database in all threads.

1. As far I know, if all threads have same instance of database then
   database access is serialized. I read in a [blog](https://medium.com/@gwendal.roue/four-different-ways-to-handle-sqlite-concurrency-db3bcc74d00e) that in serialized
   mode only one thread can read and write in database. However
   according to [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) docs, read enables shared lock hence multiple
   thread can read simultaneously. So when using single instance of db,
   default locking criteria of sqlite which allows multiple read and
   one write operation is followed or not?
2. According to sqlite docs, while writing to database first reserved lock is enabled and if any other write operation tries to get
   Reserved lock then write attempt fails and db returns SQLITE_BUSY.
   But if I am trying to run two write operation consequently from
   different threads I am never getting this error. Does it mean that
   write operation are queued and It's guaranteed that we will never
   get SQLITE_BUSY error, hence write operation will never fail?
3. I am doing a long insert operation(@Insert) in one thread(Thread1) and reading database in another thread(Thread2). If
   I start Thread2  just after Thread1, Read operation does not return the new
   inserted data in Thread1, so reading is happening before insertion.
   Is it happening because initially write enables Reserved lock and
   during this time new shared lock can be acquired @[sqlite
   docs](https://www.sqlite.org/search?q=locking.).

Sorry for a long question.