# Not able to read updated data in sqlite database

Tags: android

I already asked this as a part of question [multi threadaing with room database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436197/multi-threading-with-room-database-in-android).
I am accessing room database from multiple threads in android however using same instance of databse in all threads.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){ 
  db.getInstance().taskdao().insertAll(list)
}).start();

new Thread(new Runnable(){
  List<Task> data = db.getInstance().taskDao.loadAll();
}).start();
```

However data returned is null and I guess loadAll() is getting exeucted before insertAll() completes. Note that in actual code I am using Rxjava and hence I make sure that I  read data after loadAll() is completed. Why this happening since sqlite enables lock to make sure serialize access.

Comment: Should the DB or threading implementation matter? What if it changes in Android X? You can take matters into your own hands by either calling the methods sequentially on the same thread or invoking a callback to start loadAll once insertAll is complete.

Comment: @Elletlar: In my final app, I called loadAll after insertAll is complete. I  wanted to know why this is happening, to have a better understanding of Lock in sqlite. PCMIIW, What I could understand from sqlite docs is that write operation first enables a Reserved lock and writes data to **page cache**, meanwhile read operation can acquire shared lock and reads the data.

Comment: @Elletlar: Could you Please confirm that the result I got and  explanation I gave are consistent or not?

Comment: I understand what you're asking and how that differs from your RxJava implementation but I'd have to research it to answer with confidence with regards to all the details. But you could modify your stress test such that 1. It is inserting an extraordinary amount records, say more 10K  2. In the other thread loop through acquiring all the available records while logging count of the number of items returned.

Comment: @Elletlar: I did enough experiments. I read RoomDatabase source code, it's in WAL mode and insert, delete, update are wrapped in a transaction(using db.beginTransaction). beginTransaction is a transaction in exclusive mode. I tried first inserting 10k records and then read that. If I wrap the read query in a transaction(using db.beginTransaction) then I am able to read newly inserted data, otherwise not. Please go throough my codes, explaination is given in readme.md: [RoomIssue](https://github.com/amitkvikram/RoomIssue)

Comment: @Elletlar: One thing I got to know is that  in WAL mode, while writing the EXCLUSIVE and RESERVED locks are on the log and not on the database[link](https://unifaceinfo.com/docs/1000/Uniface_Library_HTML/ulibrary/SLE_Locking_B33EF9F17B6F4EDE8821F4EA355D52B2.html). So maybe that's why I am able to read from the database. But why wrapping the read inside a transaction is making everything right(by reading only when writing is completed).

Answer (score 2):

If you try to read immediately after wrinting try to set a callback.
You must wait till function of inserting completes.
Suppose it takes **10ms to write** into db and **5ms to start the thread and go to next thread** to start (the one that reads). **The reading thread starts reading at 6th ms while writing is not yet completed** and will return unexpected result.
Better to use an `AsyncTask` to handle callback.
Simple example:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            db.getInstance().taskdao().insertAll(list);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            CallBack c = (CallBack) context; // your activity that implements context
            c.onComplete();
        }
    }
```

and for interface and overriding:

```
interface CallBack {
        void onComplete();
    }
```

and implement it in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onComplete() {
    //Now read it
}
```

Comment: @Skilson: I implemented it in the way you described. But I want to know why my code is not working as expected.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to read exactly after writing from two different thread. What I expected that read operation will only be started once write operation is completed.

Comment: That's your problem.. Consider it takes 10ms to write into database and after that reading is possible, while it takes 5ms to start a thread and goto next thread to start reading. When reading is in progress writing is not yet completed and it will return null or unexpected result.

Comment: While writing, sqlite database enables lock which stops any other read or write operation from accessing the database.

Comment: Try running reading thread after a few seconds of writing and observe the result.

Comment: If I wrap the read query inside a transaction, database is read only when write is completed.

Comment: I guess that's what it is supposed to be. No reading during writing.

Comment: That happens only when we wrap  read query inside a transaction. I wanted to know why this is happening. I mean, update delete and insert operations are automatically wrapped in a transaction with EXCLUSIVE mode. Since exclusive lock stops other operation from getting executed, why if I don't wrap read query inside a transaction and run it just after write call, I am not getting the data inserted in write operation.