# Result of query is setting application variable late

Tags: android, fragment, android-room

I have one `Fragment`. For the `OnClickListener()` of all the views that are in the fragment I made another `class UtilClickListener`. There I am making db call on `spinner` `onItemSelected` using `room persistence database`. The `database` call first inserts data to the table and then updates an application variable in my application.

So I am trying to access the updated application variable on the `spinner` `onItemSelected()` just after the database call. But the variable is not updating at once, later when I click on other views of the `fragment` then I get the updated value.

`Fragment` code:

```
public class Calculator extends Fragment   {

 @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Spinner ageSpinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_how_old);
        ageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new UtilOnClickListener(this));
CRSCalculatorAdapter ageListAdapter = new CRSCalculatorAdapter(rootView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Arrays.asList(rootView.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.age_group)) );
        ageSpinner.setAdapter(ageListAdapter);
}
}
```

UtilOnClickListener class code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
 switch (parentSpinnerId[1]) {

            case "spinner_how_old}":

                mGlobals.setAge(parent.getSelectedItem().toString());
                CRSDatabaseInitializer.populateAsync(CRSDatabase.getDatabase(view.getContext()), crsCalculator.getContext(), Constants.QUERY_TYPE_ALL);
               mListener.onChangeActionBarTitle(Integer.valueOf(mGlobals.getFinalScore())); // Here I am updating score in the action bar which is updating late on the next view click

                break;
}
```

"CRSDatabaseInitializer" is calling an Asynctask for the database call.

Here is the database initializer code:

```
public class CRSDatabaseInitializer {
  public static void populateAsync(@NonNull final CRSDatabase db, Context context, String typeOfQuery) {

        PopulateDbAsync task = new PopulateDbAsync(db, typeOfQuery);
}

 private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final CRSDatabase mDb;
        private final String mQueryType;

        PopulateDbAsync(CRSDatabase db, String queryType) {
            mDb = db;
            mQueryType = queryType;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {

 int scoreOfAge = Integer.valueOf(getScoreOnAge(mDb));
            mGlobals.setFinalScore(scoreOfAge); // this is the application variable I need to update.
return null;

}

public static int getScoreOnAge(CRSDatabase db) {

        int userScore = 0;
        if (mGlobals.getAge() != null) {
            userScore = Integer.valueOf(db.ageScoreDao().getScore(mGlobals.getAge(), mGlobals.getMarriedOrNot()));
        }
        return userScore;
    }
}
```

Adding more codes from CRSDatabaseInitializer where I am inserting my data into the room database:

```
private static void insertNocCode(CRSDatabase db) {


        NocCode nocData = new NocCode();
        List<String[]> str = insertData(db, "nocCodes.csv");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
            nocData.setmNocCode(str.get(i)[0]);
            nocData.setmTitle(str.get(i)[1]);
            nocData.setmSkilltype(str.get(i)[2]);
            addCRSData(db, nocData);


        }
    }
```

insertData(Database db, String filename); is the method where I am reading a csv file and inserting all the columns in the csv file.

```
public static List<String[]> insertData(CRSDatabase db, String fileName) {
        String[] str = new String[5];
        ArrayList<String[]> stringArray = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(mContext.getAssets()
                    .open(fileName));

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str = line.split(",");
                stringArray.add(str);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally

        {
        }
        return stringArray;
    }
```

And the insert method definition:

```
private static NocCode addCRSData(final CRSDatabase db, NocCode nocCode) {
        db.nocCodeDao().insert(nocCode);
        return nocCode;
    }
```

Comment: Which variable you are updating?

Comment: mGlobals.setFinalScore(scoreOfAge); I am updating this variable..which I am later accessing from the fragment class.

Comment: You can leave this discussion if you got your answer. Where are you inserting data to table?

Comment: I am inserting data in the Database Initializer class "CRSDatabaseInitializer" in its doInBackground method.

Comment: Room Database is in WAL mode. Untill the data inserted in database is commited, other read operation can be performed from other thread. But you are inserting and reading using the same thread, so you can not read untill insert operation is complete. It will be helpful if you could give the code of insert operation also. One good solution is to wrap your read operation inside a transaction then reading only be performed when insertion is complete. However I will suggest you to use Rx-java.

Comment: I have added more codes where I am doing the insertion operation. I am using room database for the first time. It would be great if you could give an example how to read the columns through query inside a transaction. thanks a lot

Comment: Wrap everything inside db.beginTransaction and db.endTransactiom. Read about it on google dev guide. EDIT: Learn about Rx-java.

Comment: You can remove asynctask when using rxjava. You can do the task on a background thread and get notified when it completes. You can also chain insertion and read using flatmap operator. If interested I can add that as an answer.

Comment: Please add that as an answer, I will try to implement that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the update of this problem that I was going through. I solved the issue using handler. When I am making the database call, I am letting the DB to update the variable first , then I am running one handler to get the updated value later in the fragment. 
Here is the code I updated in the UtilOnClickListener class.

```
private static class MyHandler extends Handler {}
    private final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler();

    public static class UtilRunner implements Runnable {
        private final WeakReference<Calculator> mActivity;

        public UtilRunner(Calculator activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<Calculator>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Calculator activity = mActivity.get();

            if (activity.getContext() instanceof MainActivity) {
                OnActionBarListener   mListener = (OnActionBarListener) activity.getContext();
                Globals mGlobals = (Globals) activity.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                mListener.onChangeActionBarTitle(mGlobals.getFinalScore());

            }
        }
    }
```

And I am running the handler from OnClick of the views:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle this. In your case I am not able to understand why read operation is getting executed before inserted data is committed even though you are inserting and reading from the same thread. You can have a look on this discussion: [stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445068/not-able-to-read-updated-data-in-sqlite-database), what I learned from this discussion is that it's always better to take control in your hand because database internal implementation might change from time to time. Let's see the soution:

1. Wrap the read query inside a transaction either by using annotation @Transaction in Dao class or by wrapping the code for insertion in db.beginTransaction and db.endTransaction.[devGuide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction()). This ensures that read can't happen while database is being written.
2. What I find best for this is using Rx-Java [See Introdution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htIXKI5gOQU). You can do the insertion and then get notified when it completes and perform the read operation. Since insert operation will not return anything, wrap it inside Completable.fromAction. Completable observable has operator **obs1.andThen(obs2)**, as clear from the name first obs1 is completed then only obs2 is executed. Note that your db.ageScoreDao().getScore(..) method should return an observable, hence wrap the return value in an Observable;

   `Completable.fromAction(new Action(){`

   ```
       @Override
       public void run() throws Exception {
           db.nocCodeDao().insert(nocCode);
       }
   }).andThen(return db.ageScoreDao().getScore(..)
     .subscribeOn(Scheduler.io())   //do database query on io thread
     .observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
     .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>(){

         @Override
         public void onNext(Object o) {
              //Here you update the variable
         }
         @Override
         public void onError(Throwable e) {..}
         @Override
         public void onComplete() {..}
     });
   ```